# ASP.NET InsertItemTemplate always visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a ListView. At the moment I have to click in a Button to show the `InsertItemTemplate`, as shown below.

`Default.aspx`:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <ul>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </ul>
    <asp:Button ID="New" Text='New' CommandName="Create" OnClick="Novo_Click" runat="server" />
</LayoutTemplate>
```

`Default.aspx.cs`:

```
protected void Novo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewID.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.LastItem;
}
```

How can I have the `InsertItemTemplace` visible without needing to click a button?

Comment: I don't really find it clear what you're asking..

Comment: I think it is clear: How to show the InsertItemTemplate content **without** using the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add that line in the ListView declaration: 
**InsertItemPosition="LastItem"** to show, the template, at the end or

**InsertItemPosition="FirstItem"** to show, the template, in the top

 [The default is InsertItemPosition.None, which indicates that the InsertItemTemplate content will not be rendered by the ListView control.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.insertitemposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<asp:ListView ID="ContactsListView" 
  DataSourceID="ContactsDataSource" 
  DataKeyNames="ContactID"
  OnItemInserted="ContactsListView_ItemInserted"  
  InsertItemPosition="LastItem"
  runat="server">
    ...
</asp:ListView>
```